# Beginner: How to store data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a rails 4 app ,where I'd like to store questions and answers in some form of a document or in the database and then display them on a specific webpage and have users answer these questions.

For example: I would have a webpage called /questions and there would be a question such as "Do you like Math or Science" -> If the user chose Math for the answer it would lead them to a different question than if they had chosen Science.

**Question: How can I store questions or any piece of data in my rails app and then display them in my view if need be?**

Comment: So, what's your question? ^^

Comment: How can I store questions or any piece of data in my rails app and display them in my view?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay look - you really need to focus on asking specific questions on here. People get paid to provide opinionated answers (consultants) - SO is mainly for providing specific information about specific questions

Nonetheless, I will help you out as I'm guessing you're new:

---

**Ror**

*Saving* data is one of the most elementary functions of Rails - it's an [MVC (model view controller) framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which means that it can take any input (from your view), configure it in your controller, and finally save it in your model (to your database):

[image]

Rails is one of the most efficient, simple & extensible platforms for creating, storing & associating data; and is designed *around* that functionaliy

--

**MVC**

To get started with Rails, there are several things you need to consider.

Firstly, you need to appreciate that Rails is built on *Ruby*, which makes it [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This means that everything you do with Rails has to revolve *around* objects, including everything from your routes to your `controller` actions

This is important because so many newbies don't know about Rails' OOP capabilities, and consequently create application-flows which are disjointed & broken. The *right* way to create Rails-based applications is to put the object at the center of the flow, which will be apparent in a second

-

Secondly, as Rails is an MVC framework, it handles requests somewhat differently than "normal" applications. It does this by taking your request, sending it to your routes & then processing a *controller* action. This action then allows you to build data from the *model*, which you can then display in the *view*

You can read great beginner resources for Rails here:

> - [Rails official beginners' guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)
> - [Getting started with Rails Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails?view=comments)

---

**Question**

In regards to your question, here is what you need to do:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "questions#index"
resources :question do #-> domain.com/questions
   resources :answers
end
```

Here is what you need

```
#app/models/question.rb
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :answers
end

#app/models/answer.rb
Class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :question
end

#app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
Class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @questions = Question.all
   end

   def new
      @question = Question.new
   end

   def create
      @question = Question.new(question_params)
      redirect_to @question if @question.save
   end

   def show
      @question = Question.find params[:id]
   end

   private

   def question_params
       params.require(:question).permit(:your, :question, :attributes)
   end
end

#app/views/questions/index.html.erb
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
   <%= link_to question.title, question %>
<% end %>

#app/views/questions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Flow**

This will give you the ability to access the route `domain.com/questions/new` to create a new question, and if you want, you can then add some `nested` functionality to accommodate answers for those questions

I would highly recommend firstly thinking about what you want to achieve, rather than how you are going to do it. This will give you clarity on how you're meant to create the structure, consequently making it much simpler to implement

Answer (score 2):

When you created your Rails application, it created a config/database.yml file. This file tells Rails where to store your data. By default, it stores the data in a sqlite database. This is a fine option for learning how to use Rails.

Rails uses database migrations to create the structure of the database.

The easiest way I can think of to get you started would be to use a scaffold. A scaffold creates a Rails model, a database migration, and all the views and controllers you'll need to get started. On the command line, run:

```
bin/rails generate scaffold Question question:string category:string
```

The will show a list of all the files it created, and the files are worth looking into.

Now that the files are generated, run:

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

This will migrate your database. The database migration will add a questions table to your database, with two string columns, question and category, and a a few Rails-specific columns. You can see the structure of the table it created in db/schema.rb.

After you migrate your database, you'll be able to run the rails server with:

```
bin/rails server
```

Once the server is running, you can see your list of questions in a browser at localhost:3000/questions. Of course, you start with no questions, but the scaffold added code that will let you add, edit, and delete questions.

There are a lot of good tutorials for the next steps, such as associating answers with questions.

Comment: I appreciate you writing this answer but it's not what I'm looking for. My question is how do I store and retrieve data such as questions? Not have a possible user create a question.

Comment: Is your question how to restrict users so they can only view questions? Usually, as the site admin, you'd want the ability to add/edit/delete in the UI so you can manage the questions. Or, are you asking about how to structure the questions in the database? How to populate the questions without a UI?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Ruby on Rails Guides. They are an excellent resource for learning how to create Rails applications

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to rails too and found taking some time out to really get my head around the MVC framework and how it works really helped be to then take a step forward and apply things in the way i needed to. The rails guide listed above is great. It really helped me to break down the MVC into the three individual aspects and understand how they worked individually before putting them together. There are some really good projects with screencasts out there which helps put this into practice. I particularly like base rails and the odin project.